# check type of variable in HTML

Tags: html, angular

In my view class i am rendering some data, i am getting a variable and i want to check that if the type of variable is Boolean than i want to show a switch button for it, but if the type is number then i want to show a slider for it.

```
<div *ngFor="let attribute of agent.attributes; let i = index">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s2">
          <mat-card>
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-title>{{agent.attributes[i].name}}</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
              <div class="center">{{agent.attributes[i].value}}</div>
              <!-- for this value i want to check the type for it, if it is boolean then 
              a switch button should show and if type is number than a slider show be shown -->
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions>
              <button mat-button>SAVE</button>
            </mat-card-actions>
          </mat-card>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Write a simple `typeOf` method to check the type:

ts:

```
typeOf(value) {
  return typeof value;
}
```

And then use it in your template:

```
<div *ngIf="typeOf(var1) === 'boolean'">switch button</div>
<div *ngIf="typeOf(var1) === 'number'">slider</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-typeof-in-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `typeof`, and put it into an `ngIf`

```
typeof i === "number"
```

and

```
typeof i === "boolean"
```

Comment: no you can't for angular8 it gives you below msg `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token === at column 10 in [typeof i === 'number'] in`

Comment: Not sure if this worked before, but it definitely doesn't work now.